# Visual C++/MFC Disable Windows sounds

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, audio, mfc

I'm building a C++/MFC desktop app that shares a lot of data with an USB device.
Because of how this devices works I need to close and open the virtual COM I use, severl times per minute.

Everything works well, but I would like to stop the annoying Windows USB connected/disconnected suound, that comes up every time I connect or disconnect the device.

So my question is: is there a way to disable/enable Windows event sounds (or a single event sound, even better) through my C++ code?
Obviously I could somehow turn down the volume, but that's not what I want, since it would stop sounds from every other app.
Is there a way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is configured with Control Panel > Sounds > Sounds tab > Device Dis/Connect.  And stored in the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\  Whether you can hack the registry key without telling Windows about it is something you'll have to try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try to implement it. Though I ask if it is polite for an app to keep modifying register keys multiple times per minute. Does the user who run the app need admin permission for modifying them?

Comment: Of course it is not polite, changing the user's preferences without telling him about it is one of the most hostile things you can do.  But as long as you don't want to address the real problem, you'll get what you ask for at this web site.

Comment: A little update.. I implemented the suggested solution and it seems to work properly as I meant.. So thank you :)

Comment: @Hans Passant - those "moral" issues are easily resolved by popping one message box to the user: "Would you like to disable Connect/Disconnect audible signals for the duration of this process?" :)

Comment: @VladFeinstein That's definitely something I should add :)